# ViewPager + Picasso + multiple images from URL String array

Tags: android, android-viewpager, picasso, android-photoview

Please help me. I'm following the example ViewPagerActivity from sample PhotoView of Chris Banes (https://github.com/chrisbanes/PhotoView) and I want to change the drawable with Picasso URL images. So, I'm trying to put multiple images in HackyViewPager via Picasso String array of urls.

my xml ViewPager:

```
<my.package.HackyViewPager
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/view_pager"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="200dp" />
```

in onCreate:

```
...      
ViewPager viewPager = (HackyViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
viewPager.setAdapter(new SamplePagerAdapter());
```

I have a String array of URL's obtained from one single String stringDefinitionGemstonesPhoto

```
String[] strAry = stringDefinitionGemstonesPhoto.split(",");
```

and the final code in SamplePageAdapter is:

```
static class SamplePagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    private String stringDefinitionGemstonesPhoto = ("https://geology.com/minerals/photos/calcite-marble-127.jpg, https://geology.com/minerals/photos/calcite-concrete.jpg");
    private  String[] strAry = stringDefinitionGemstonesPhoto.split(",");


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return strAry.length;
    }

    @Override
    public View instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        PhotoView photoView = new PhotoView(container.getContext());

        System.out.println(strAry[position]);
        Picasso.get().load(strAry[position]).into(photoView);

        container.addView(photoView, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        return photoView;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        container.removeView((View) object);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view == object;
    }

}
```

Only one image is showing, when I'm sliding the next photo is empty/blank. In the Log system print out the links which are splitted correctly.
What is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see something wrong, that is

```
for(int i= 0; i < numbers.length; i++){
                System.out.println(strAry[i]);
                System.out.println(strAry[position]);
                Picasso.get().load(strAry[position]).into(photoView);
            }
```

should be

```
            System.out.println(strAry[position]);
            Picasso.get().load(strAry[position]).into(photoView);
```

**UPDATE**

I found an issue that `Picasso` or `Glide` can not work well in `instantiateItem()`, [see more](https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues/935)

So my solution is not using above lib anymore, we try to request url by hand, this way is not better because of performance issues but it's worked.

Here is my solution

```
class SamplePagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    private String stringDefinitionGemstonesPhoto = ("https://geology.com/minerals/photos/calcite-marble-127.jpg, https://geology.com/minerals/photos/calcite-concrete.jpg");
    private String[] strAry = stringDefinitionGemstonesPhoto.split(",");


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return strAry.length;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(@NonNull ViewGroup container, int position) {
        PhotoView photoView = new PhotoView(container.getContext());
        try {
            new DownloadImageTask(photoView)
                    .execute(strAry[position]);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Log.e("Error", ex.getMessage());
        }

        container.addView(photoView, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        return photoView;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(@NonNull ViewGroup container, int position, @NonNull Object object) {
        container.removeView((View) object);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(@NonNull View view, @NonNull Object object) {
        return view == object;
    }

    public class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
        private ImageView bmImage;

        DownloadImageTask(ImageView bmImage) {
            this.bmImage = bmImage;
        }

        protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
            String urlDisplay = urls[0];
            Bitmap myImage = null;
            try {
                InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urlDisplay).openStream();
                myImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return myImage;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
            bmImage.setImageBitmap(result);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: doesn't work, see my updated question, it shows only one image, but my Log says that I have all 3 URL splitted.

Comment: @ApopeiAndreiIonut are you sure 2nd and 3th url is a valid url? can you show them out?

Comment: sure, I updated the code/question, I have only two links to simplify the problem

Comment: @ApopeiAndreiIonut well done, I will create a demo to reproducing your issue and come back later

Comment: I appreciate your time! In the meantime will try to solve.

Comment: @ApopeiAndreiIonut I updated my answer, please take a look

Comment: Thank you very much @GianhTran

Answer (score 2):

No need to use numbers array separately , update adapter class

```
static class SamplePagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    private static String[] strAry = stringDefinitionGemstonesPhoto.split(",");


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return strAry.length;
    }

    @Override
    public View instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        PhotoView photoView = new PhotoView(container.getContext());

            System.out.println(strAry[position]);
            Picasso.get().load(strAry[position]).into(photoView);

        container.addView(photoView, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        return photoView;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        container.removeView((View) object);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view == object;
    }

}
```

Comment: When I put that two lines of code (i.e., container.addView... and return photoView;) outside the } ... i get errors Class 'SamplePageAdapter' must either be declared abstract or implement abstract method 'isViewFromObject(View, Object)' in 'PageAdapter'.

Comment: sorry its because of one extra closing brace,I edited the code and removed it now.
you can check

Comment: It doesn't work yet, I don't see the second image, see my updated question.